# Why does a borrowed variable not change when the borrowed from variable changes?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and trying to understand the borrowing principle.

I have the following code:

```rs
fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let largest_nbr = &number_list[0];

    println!("The largest number is {}", largest_nbr);

    let number_list = vec![102, 34, 6000, 89, 54, 2, 43, 8];

    println!("The largest number is {}", largest_nbr);
}
```

When I execute `cargo run` I get this result:

```
> The largest number is 34
> The largest number is 34
```

I expected the second line to say `102` is the largest number because `largest_nbr` borrows from `number_list`, so the pointer is showing at the storage of `number_list`. When the value of `number_list` changes, shouldn't the value of `largest_nbr` also change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line:

```rust
let number_list = vec![102, 34, 6000, 89, 54, 2, 43, 8];
```

does **not** modify the original `number_list` variable. It creates a new one and names it identically, shadowing the original name.

In simpler terms that means that now two `number_list` variables exist, but the first one is no longer accessible because the second one has taken over the name. The `largest_nbr` variable, however, references the first one.

Note that what you are trying here is impossible, because you cannot modify the array while you borrow parts of it. I guess this is why you added a `let` to it, because if you would simply write `number_list = vec![102, 34, 6000, 89, 54, 2, 43, 8]`, without the `let`, you would get an error that tells you that you can't modify it while it is borrowed in `largest_nbr`.

See:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let largest_nbr = &number_list[0];

    println!("The largest number is {}", largest_nbr);

    number_list = vec![102, 34, 6000, 89, 54, 2, 43, 8];

    println!("The largest number is {}", largest_nbr);
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `number_list` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:8:5
   |
4  |     let largest_nbr = &number_list[0];
   |                        ----------- borrow of `number_list` occurs here
...
8  |     number_list = vec![102, 34, 6000, 89, 54, 2, 43, 8];
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `number_list` occurs here
9  |
10 |     println!("The largest number is {}", largest_nbr);
   |                                          ----------- borrow later used here
```

Comment: Thank you! So in other words, the first `number_list`'s storage still exists and `largest_number` is pointing at its storage. But accessing it is impossible because it is shadowed by the new declaration.

Comment: @BonisTech Exactly :)

Answer (score -1):

You’re not changing value of `number_list`, you’re shadowing it. And even if you would’ve changed your `number_list`, `largest_number` wouldn’t have changed (just dropped). Why? Because a `Vec` is basically just a pointer, length and capacity and is not connected to a buffer. Only arrays (not slices!) are real buffers. So how do you *change* your `Vec`? Nohow! You can’t mutate a variable while it’s still borrowed as immutable. And you don’t need this, so don’t try.

Comment: *"And you don’t need this, so don’t try"* - I'd partially disagree with this statement. Especially people coming from other languages like C/C++ will feel that this is very much needed. I'd rather say that there are viable alternatives that are better suited for a borrow checked language.

Comment: @Finomnis, I meant that you _really_ don’t need this in terms of Rust. It doesn’t mean you can’t preform such an unsafe operation in Rust, but I’m not gonna show a newbie how to do this. I agree that there are better alternatives.

Comment: I agree, and worded like this it makes more sense :) It's just that way you worded it will cause the following reaction in C/C++ programmers: "If something easy like this isn't possible in Rust, that what kind of stupid language is this?" I've seen that reaction several times, so it's important to state why and point out alternatives instead of just saying "you don't need this".

Comment: Thanks for both your engagements. I know that it's not a good idea to execute such code. I was reading the docs and saw a similar code and tried to modify it to better understand the mechanics of the language. The code I posted is 90% copied from the docs.